# ajax.responseText returns undefined

Tags: php, ajax

I am using stack exchange api to get question from stackoverflow

```
function importQuestion(){//IMPORTS QUESTION
    $("import_status").innerHTML = "Validating Url ...";
    var url = $("stackoverflow_url").value;//User typed URL 
    var id = get_question_id_from_url(url);//Returns Question id from url
    var ajax_response = get_stackoverflow_question(id);//Returns json data form ajax api
    $("import_status").innerHTML = "Contacting stackoveflow.com ...";
    process_question_json(ajax_response);
    $("import_status").innerHTML = "Question is in place :D";
}
```

This function request server file which contact stack exchange api

```
function get_stackoverflow_question(id){
    debugger;
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
            response = ajax.responseText;
            return response;
        }
    }
    ajax.open("GET","/ajax_call_files/import_question.php?id=33449986",true);
    ajax.send();
}
```

import_question.php file code is working fine i have manully checked it. It returns json data of question

`get_stackoverflow_question(id);` its returning undefined

If i add `console.log(ajax.resonseText);`
it prints data in console after `process_question_json(ajax_response);` is called and this function throw error  because ajax_response is undefined

I have resolved this issue with `async:false` but this is deprecated. Are there any alternative to this

I do not won't to use any third party libs

And What is the reason that ajax takes time to get response. I haven't encountered such problems before

Comment: can provide the info instead `get_stackoverflow_question` method ?

Comment: What info?
its not executing the if condition part

Comment: Use third-party library like `jQuery`. `$.ajax` is an alternative to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Anyway i can do without jQuery or any third pary libs. I want to do it in pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous. So you must use callbacks.

```
function get_stackoverflow_question(id){
    debugger;
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){

            callback(ajax.responseText);
        }
    }
    ajax.open("GET","/ajax_call_files/import_question.php?id=33449986",true);
    ajax.send();
}


get_stackoverflow_question(function(response) {
    // do your work here
    alert(response);
});
```

Comment: What will responseData contain?

Comment: responseData is the object of your result. You need to use this object to get responseText.

Comment: object of my result should be ajax because i am creating ajax to `XMLHttpRequest()`

Comment: inside this function you need to use this obj as parameter. And ajax object is working outside that function.

Comment: Can you add more details to code i am not getting what are you trying to say.

Comment: Just try this and run first. Is it working or not ?.